# EF code first database: login failed for same user for one of two databases, equivalent connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014, connection-string

I'm trying to create two databases with SQL Server 2014, Entity Framework. One is created "automatically" with asp.net identity and the other one I create using a seed method in `Configuration.cs`.

Both have the same SQL login in the connection string, but only the identity database is created. For the other one, the following error occurs:

> The underlying provider failed on Open. [...]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed.

Here are the connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AntContext" 
         connectionString="Database=dbname;User Id=user; Password=mypw;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Database=dbnameidentity;User Id=user; Password=mypw;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />      
</connectionStrings>
```

Checking in SQL Server Management Studio, the database `dbnameidentity` is created and even populated with seeding data from `Configuration.cs`, but for the other one the login fails.

I have no idea why this happens. I'll provide more information if necessary. Thanks.

Here's the head of my seed method.

```
 protected override void Seed(IdentityDbContext context)
 {
        var antcontext = new DataContext.AntContext();
```

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an *initialiser* set for your context. This means it will not try to create the database. If you want to ensure the DB is created, then you can use the [`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.createdatabaseifnotexists-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) initialiser, for example:

```
public class AntContext: DbContext 
{
    public AntContext(): base("AntContext") 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AntContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AntContext>());    
    }

    //snip
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it did work and now i have my Database generated.